# Recover a date with SQLite

Tags: sql, ios, date, sqlite

I'm trying to recover a date with SQLite on iOS.

This date (saved in selectedDate) is a variable NSDate. I convert NSDate to NSString (saved in dateString).

```
//Code:

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyyMMdd"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];

[formatter release];


NString *sentence = (@"SELECT description, date_from FROM Tasks WHERE date_from = %@", dateString);

//Warning: Expression result unused  :(
```

If I put a default date, for example: SELECT... WHERE date_from = '20120719', it runs. How can I solve it?

Sorry for my English ;)   Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks to me like you never execute the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try `LIKE` is place of `=` ?

```
date_from LIKE '20120719'
```

and

```
NSString *sentence = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT description, date_from FROM Tasks WHERE date_from = %@", dateString];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!                                                  NSString *sentence = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT description, date_from FROM Tasks WHERE date_from = %@", dateString]; //is OK